# Magic square code loop

Tags: java, loops

This is the code for a method which creates a magic square. `n` is the length of the square. It has to look like:

```
static int[][] magicSquare(int n) {
```

int[][] square=new int[n][n];

I don't understand this  `k=(k+1)%n;` especially, why is it `%n` ?? Doesn´t that put `k` to `1` every loop again?

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
   in k=i;
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
        square[i][j]=k+1;
        k=(k+1)%n;


1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
3 4 1 2
4 1 2 3
```

Comment: Please code-format the magic square. It's currently on 1 line and looks confusing.

Comment: Also, why are you using the first loop when all it does is set `k = n - 1`?

Comment: oh sorry, the numbers appear different now as when i wrote the post

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: That´s how it looks like

Comment: `k=(k+1)%n` is incrementing the value of `k` and `%n` is the [**Modulo Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators). This is done to prevent the value of `k` to reach to `n`. When `k=n`, set `k=0`. So `k=(k+1)%n` can be simplified as `k = (k+1==n) ? 0 : k+1`

Answer (score 1):

The % in Java is used for modular division. Whenever the operator is applied the right-hand operand will be subtracted as many times as it can from the left-hand operand and what's left will be the output. You can easily check it by dividing the left-hand operand by the right-hand operand and take the leftover as an integer. In the case of `a%b` it will be like 
    `a - (a/b)*b`.

here are some examples:

```
10 % 4 = 2 // 2*4 = 8 + 2 = 10
10 % 5 = 0 // 2*5 = 10 + 0 = 10
0 % 4 = 0 // result here is 0 thus 0*4 = 0 + 0 = 0
// if you try to extract 4 from 0, you will not succeed and what's left will be returned (which was originally 0 and it's still 0)...
```

In your case:

```
k = (k + 1) % n;
```

is assuring that the value of k will never exceed 4, thus if it is dividable by 4 then it will be divided and the leftover will be written there. In the case when k is exactly 4 you will have the value of 0 written down into k but since you are always adding `k + 1` it is writing  the value of 1.

For beginners I do recommend to print the values you are interested in and observe how do the data migrate. Here I've added some printlns for you just to get the idea. Run the code and test it yourself. I do believe the things are going to be a bit cleaner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 4;

    int[][] square = new int[n][n];

    System.out.println("--------------");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        int k = i;

        System.out.println("Filling magic cube line " + (i + 1) + ". The k variable will start from " + i + "."); // i initial value is 0 so we add 1 to it just to get the proper line number.

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            System.out.println("Filling array index [" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + (k + 1)); // array indexes start from 0 aways and end at array.length - 1, so in case of n = 4, last index in array is 3.

            square[i][j] = k + 1; // add 1 to k so the value will be normalized (no 0 entry and last entry should be equal to n).

            k = (k + 1) % n; // reset k if it exceeds n value.
        }

        System.out.println("--------------");

    }

    Arrays.stream(square).forEach(innerArray -> {
        Arrays.stream(innerArray).forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
    });
}
```

You could always play around and refactor the code as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 4;

    int[][] square = new int[n][n];

    System.out.println("--------------");

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        int k = i;

        System.out.println("Filling magic cube line " + i + ". The k variable will start from " + i + ".");

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            System.out.println("Filling array index [" + (i - 1) + "][" + (j - 1) + "] = " + k); // array indexes start from 0 aways and end at array.length - 1, so in case of n = 4, last index in array is 3. Subtract both i and j with 1 to get the proper array indexes.

            square[i - 1][j - 1] = k;

            k = (k + 1) % n; // reset k if it exceeds n value.
        }

        System.out.println("--------------");

    }

    Arrays.stream(square).forEach(innerArray -> {
        Arrays.stream(innerArray).forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
    });
}
```

Remember that the array's indexing starts from 0 and ends at length - 1. In the case of 4, the first index is 0 and the last one is 3. Here is the diff of two implementations, try to see how does the indexes and values depends both on the control variables `i` and `j`.

https://www.diffchecker.com/x5lIWi4A

In the first case i and j both start from 0 and are growing till they it's values are both less than n, and in the second example they start from 1 and are growing till they are equal to n. I hope it's getting clearer now. Cheers

Comment: thanks so far, but i still don´t get it. In the first loop k+1 == 1, so [i] [j] is [1] [1] . Then k gets set to 1 again and it´s [2] [2]. Then k gets set to 1 again ...

Comment: Oh, I will update my answer with the full flow of that one.